# How do I access Ruby/Object Attributes

Tags: ruby

The debug output looks like this:

```
!ruby/object:Business 
attributes:
  business_type: 8
  type_count: 2
```

But how do I access those attributes?

I'm feeling dumb here :/

EDIT: 
some more code from my view:

```
<% @serviceSections.each do |k,v| %>
<% c = @bc.select{|s| s.business_type == k} %>  
<%= debug(c.type_count) %>
<% end %>
```

Which just gives me the error

> undefined method `type_count' for [# < Business business_type: 8>]:Array

EDIT2

Im mostly an idiot :-) it was late....

all I needed to do was actually check:

```
<% if !c.respond_to?("type_count") %>
```

Comment: Use the dot operator. `object.attribute`

Comment: @Anand - that doesnt work - updated question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select) says : "Although in the above example it looks as though this method returns an array, it actually returns a relation object and can have other query methods appended to it, such as the other methods in ActiveRecord::QueryMethods."

With that in mind, the following should do the trick

```
c.each do |r|
  puts r.type_count
end
```

If you are sure that only one record will be returned by the `select` then the following will also work.

`<%= debug c[0].type_count %>`

Comment: Ah, so I can do "c.each do ". I'd already tried using "c[0].type_count" Its Confusing as I cant tell what sort of object it is I'm working with and I was trying to access it like an array or a hash. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could help :). To find the class name of the object you can try `c[0].class.name`

Answer (score 4):

```
Business.business_type # => 8
Business.type_count # => 2
```

This requires that in your `Business` class is an attribute reader defined, usually like this:

```
class Business
  attr_reader :business_type, :type_count
  # more code ...
end
```

If you want to `set` values in addition, you should define an attribute accessor instead:

```
class Business
  attr_accessor :business_type, :type_count
  # more code ...
end
```

Then you are able to:

```
Business.business_type = 17
Business.type_count = 22
```

Comment: Hmm... I thought it might be something like that. I've updated my code sample above. I dont have a class defined. @bc is an active record object.

Comment: `.select` returns an array. choose a single object out of this array to work with it :)

Comment: But thats the problem - I cant see how to do that.

Comment: `c = @bc.select{|s| s.business_type == k}.first` for example.